# What is the significance of the off the shelf AEM user group called everyone?

Tags: aem

In AEM, when we create a new user using the useradmin console, the newly created user gets added to an off the shelf user-group called **everyone** . What is the significance of the off the shelf group - **everyone** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the easiest way to address all users of an AEM instance. 
I think that's all there is about this group. It is just there to enable you to set ACLs that are used for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there may be lots of reasons it's set up that way.  I've administered systems where we decided to have such a group.  Unless you specifically ask the person who set it up that way, there's no way to tell what they wanted it for.

Here are just a few ideas of how I've seen such a group used:

It's a group that everyone on the machine belongs to, and not any of the daemons?  So, you can use it as a group in file ownership when you want to set some protection that applies to all users.  Or you might have that as a default and then exclude some specific users, so that people in the group can exchange permissions without those others?  Maybe it's there as a way to globally select all the accounts for *people* to do something to those accounts (e.g. set or adjust quotas).

There are probably as many possible reasons as there are UNIX sysadmins.

Comment: Hi @MAP - is your answer in context of the latest version of AEM?

Comment: My comment applies to **all** UNIX-like systems.  I don't know anything about the people who put AEM together and would not deign to put words in their mouth, if I did.  I was commenting on the many ways I've seen this sort of thing used in my 30+ years on UNIX.  As I said, if you want a real answer about why it's in that system, you have to ask the people who did it, not the general public.